# Getting no result in MLT query Solr 8.11.2

Tags: solr, drupal, lucene, drupal-8, solrcloud

I sometimes encounter situations where my Solr MLT query, using Solr version 8.11.2, yields no results, while at other times, it returns a response. I've attempted to execute the same query multiple times, and even though I anticipate a response each time, occasionally, the query results in a blank response. Here's the query I've been using:

```
http://solr.dev.ayoba.me:8983/solr/dev/mlt?mlt.fl=body&mlt.interestingTerms=details&mlt.match.include=true&mlt.mindf=0&mlt.mintf=0&q=its_nid:37645
```